# Join 2 tables to return a query with zero Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one called Doctor and one called Appointment. They both have doctor_id in common relationship. I need to be able Produce a list of doctor IDs together with the number of appointments made for each doctor with zero or more appointment. (See Picture for Table Content)

[image]

Using the Code below I can have the list of doctor) id as well as the number of appointment, but it doesn't display the doctors with ZERO Appointment as it is in the Doctor list. What modification do I need to do?

```
SELECT doctor_id, COUNT(DISTINCT appt_time) AS No_APP FROM appointment GROUP BY doctor_id;
```

This is what I get from it

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_id, COUNT(appointment.appt_time) AS No_APP 
FROM doctor
LEFT JOIN appointment 
ON appointment.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id
GROUP BY doctor.doctor_id;
```

Comment: DISTINCT actually makes a wrong result IMO. What about same appointment times in different days?

Answer (score 1):

Use left join:

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_id, COUNT(appt_time) AS No_APP FROM doctor LEFT JOIN appointment ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id GROUP BY doctor.doctor_id;
```

It should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select 
  d.doctor_id
  ,count(distinct a.appt_time) as No_APP 
from doctor d 
left join appointment a on d.doctor_id=a.doctor_id
group by d.doctor_id
```

Comment: You should remove the "distinct" though, as it will (theoretically) give you the wrong answer for identical appointment times on different days, as pointed out by ejzy's comment on the other answer.  Probably won't happen in real life, but it's better to keep the logic clean.

Comment: True .. I never used the date split into date and time .. so when I saw the original code I didn't question ..

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_id, COUNT(DISTINCT appt_date, appt_time) AS No_APP 
FROM doctor 
LEFT JOIN appointment
ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id
GROUP BY doctor_id;
```

Comment: Fixed. Thanks. I also added appt_date to the list of 'distinct' columns. I think this is more in line with what you want.